Running a custom query with @Query annotation in spring data jdbc is giving unexpected results
i am trying to explore spring-data-jdbc. I have the following SQL schema with me
create table if not exists customer(
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);

create table if not exists customer_order(
    id serial primary key,
    customer_id bigint not null references customer (id),
    name varchar(255)
);

create table if not exists customer_profile(
    id serial primary key,
    customer_id bigint not null references customer(id),
    username text not null,
    password text not null
);

My entities are defined as follows in my program
public record Customer(@Id Integer id,
                       String name,
                       @MappedCollection(idColumn = "customer_id") Set<Profile> profile,
                       @MappedCollection(idColumn = "customer_id") Set<Order> order ) {
}
@Table("customer_order")
public record Order(@Id Integer id,
                    Integer customerId,
                    List<String> name) {
}
@Table("customer_profile")
public record Profile(@Id Integer id,
                      Integer customerId,
                      String username,
                      String password) {
}

I try to run a query that fetches customers and their record based upon their customer profile
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT c.id as id, c.name as name, co.id as customer_order_id," +
            " co.customer_id as customer_order_customer_id," +
            " co.name as customer_order_name," +
            " cp.customer_id as customer_profile_customer_id," +
            " cp.username as customer_profile_username," +
            " cp.password as customer_profile_password FROM customer c " +
            " INNER JOIN customer_order co ON c.id = co.customer_id " +
            " INNER JOIN customer_profile cp ON cp.username = :username " +
            " AND cp.customer_id = co.customer_id")
    List<Customer> getCustomerByUsername(@Param("username") final String username);
}

But in the debug logs i see 5 queries running instead of 1
2024-06-03T19:16:53.572+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2024-06-03T19:16:53.579+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT c.id as id, c.name as name, co.id as customer_order_id, co.customer_id as customer_order_customer_id, co.name as customer_order_name, cp.customer_id as customer_profile_customer_id, cp.username as customer_profile_username, cp.password as customer_profile_password FROM customer c  INNER JOIN customer_order co ON c.id = co.customer_id  INNER JOIN customer_profile cp ON cp.username = ?  AND cp.customer_id = co.customer_id]
2024-06-03T19:16:53.579+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2024-06-03T19:16:53.604+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2024-06-03T19:16:53.604+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT "customer_profile"."id" AS "id", "customer_profile"."username" AS "username", "customer_profile"."password" AS "password", "customer_profile"."customer_id" AS "customer_id" FROM "customer_profile" WHERE "customer_profile"."customer_id" = ?]
2024-06-03T19:16:53.604+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2024-06-03T19:16:53.611+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2024-06-03T19:16:53.611+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT "customer_order"."id" AS "id", "customer_order"."name" AS "name", "customer_order"."customer_id" AS "customer_id" FROM "customer_order" WHERE "customer_order"."customer_id" = ?]
2024-06-03T19:16:53.611+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2024-06-03T19:16:53.616+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2024-06-03T19:16:53.616+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT "customer_profile"."id" AS "id", "customer_profile"."username" AS "username", "customer_profile"."password" AS "password", "customer_profile"."customer_id" AS "customer_id" FROM "customer_profile" WHERE "customer_profile"."customer_id" = ?]
2024-06-03T19:16:53.616+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2024-06-03T19:16:53.619+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2024-06-03T19:16:53.619+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT "customer_order"."id" AS "id", "customer_order"."name" AS "name", "customer_order"."customer_id" AS "customer_id" FROM "customer_order" WHERE "customer_order"."customer_id" = ?]
2024-06-03T19:16:53.619+05:30 DEBUG 17828 --- [SpringDataJDBCDemo] [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource


How to make sure that spring data jdbc only runs the query i am defining in @Query and not anything else

Not that familair with Spring Data JDBC, but I suspect that is the result of the @MappedCollection it will get that information automatically. Hence additional queries.

Hi @M.Deinum MappedCollection does not fetch the information, it is used to just configure mapping for a child aggregate

And how do you think it should get those aggregates?

Did you try to add  "nativeQuery = true" flag to @Query annotation?

I think @m-deinum is right about @MappedCollection being the reason for the extra queries.
To prevent auto-generated queries being used you could try setting the Query lookup strategy to USE_DECLARED_QUERY. However, with @MappedCollection being present this would still mean that subsidiary queries would be used for the joined tables; they would just be ones that you would need to declare in other Repositories.
An option for this particular query is to remove the @MappedCollection fields, and create a constructor for Customer with parameter names that match the column names returned by your query, as you can read in this reference:

If you have a single non-zero-argument constructor whose constructor argument names match top-level column names of the row, that constructor is used. Otherwise, the zero-argument constructor is used. If there is more than one non-zero-argument constructor, an exception is thrown.

However, this seems a very restricting approach as you may well want to retrieve rows which do not have this precise structure. Also you'll have to stop using Record.
If you want a high degree of control and flexibility over the SQL you use and how it maps to objects, also look at using MyBatis.

Hi, i actually fixed this issue with a custom ResultSetExtractor, i figured out using the default result set extractor will force spring data jdbc to always run separate queries to get resultSet of each child aggregate, so i ended up mapping each row and column manually. This fixed the issue.

Great news! If you stick that down as an answer I’d happily upvote it.

The reason for the additional selects are the referenced Set instances.
Spring Data JDBC will use the provided SQL for the root entity and any one-to-one references. For collections an additional query will get executed.
To avoid that you may provide your own RowMapper or ResultSetExtractor in the @Query annotation.
Note: this is essentially what Shashank Bajpai put in a comment.
Since he didn't turn it in a proper answer for others to easily find, I did it.
